# После сборки пакета при помщи maven'а файлы ушли из-под контроля git'а

Tags: git, maven

После выполнения команды mvn clean install для некоторого пакета в проекте, написанном на Java, все файлы из этого пакета вышли из-под версионного контроля гита. Также перестали распознаваться файлы с расширением .java.
До этого много раз выполнял подобные команды и ничего подобного не происходило.
Возможно кто-то сталкивался с чем-то подобным?
P.S. Пытался просто добавить в гит эти файлы снова, но тогда их нужно комитить, а это неправильно, потому что в удаленном репозитории эти файлы есть. Может есть способ вручную добавить пути к этим потеряным файлам во внутрь гита вручную?

Comment: Похоже мавен как-то удалил эти файлы из гита. Что говорит `git log`

Comment: Помогла переустановка гита, видимо что-то с гитом произошло. К сожалению логи уже не смогу увидеть, все вычистил.